# Entity Framework Core: how to specify the same set of primary keys for all entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a number of entities and for each of them I need to specify a composite primary key:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>HasKey(vf => new 
{
   vf.col1,
   vf.col2,
   ...
   vf.col8
});
```

Is there a way to do the same for *all* entities in one go?

I tried to look into member expressions, but cannot figure out how to use it.

Comment: This is where interfaces can be handy, you can do an expression look up to get the type and then loop through each type based on that interface in `OnModelCreating` within the DbContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using mutable model in `OnModelCreating`.
I suggest to create base type/interface for entities:

```cs
public interface IEntity
{
    int Id1 { get; set; }
    int Id2 { get; set; }
}

public class MyEntity : IEntity
{
    // ...
}
```

and then do something like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    var props = new[] { nameof(IEntity.Id1), nameof(IEntity.Id2) };
    foreach (var mutableEntityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
    {
        // check if current entity type implements IEntity
        if (mutableEntityType.ClrType.IsAssignableTo(typeof(IEntity)))
        {
            mutableEntityType.SetPrimaryKey(mutableEntityType.FindProperties(props));   
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason this gives me violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key... Is there a reason for it?

Comment: @AlexS. Maybe you are inserting a duplicate one? Also check the database generation option

Comment: Yes, I screwed up in automapper - thank you for the solution, that helped a lot!